# Performance when highlighting item in list with React

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, reactjs

I have a large list, let's say 3k members. I have a component that renders this list and a component for each list item. In the outer component we have code like this:

```
const list = _.map(this.props.items, (item) => {
    return <ListItem key={item.key} {...item} />
});
```

And then in our JSX we place the list:

```
<div>
    <h3>Check out my sweet list </h3>
    { list }
</div>
```

Here's the rub: I want to show the user when they click on an item that the item has been selected. So in my `ListItem` component I have code that, based on whether or not the individual item has a `selected` property, highlights itself. **How do I stop React from rerendering the entire list, when only the selected property on a single item changes?** I'm sure I need to restructure my code somehow, but I'm not sure what structure will solve this problem. Happy to answer any and all questions and thanks in advance!

**Notes:**

- I'm not saying rendering 3k items in a list is good, just believe
  this should be, in principle, possible to do with react.
- The list isn't being literally re-rendering on the actual dom, but the virtual dom is doing the work of comparing everything, and that takes a lot of time.

Comment: Even you get an entire list, I believe react compares them in virtual dom, and only re-render those selected changed ones, do you even want that virtual dom compare to not happen?

Comment: Just offtopic - why do I keep seeing "react is not performant with a list of 1000's of items" - what kind of UX displays 1000s of items at once? Unless it's some rare case I don't see a reason not to use search/filtering/pagination/progressive loading/limits, and if the member list grows it will always eventually become disfunctional if you display everything

Comment: @fuyushimoya yes the virtual dom is taking place, so it's not the entire list getting literally re-rendered on the dom, just curious if there is a way to structure the code to avoid that preprocessing, because it's on order of seconds (and yes, yes I know this is a large example and you shouldn't render 3k items in a list).

Answer (score 6):

Okay I figured it out. Successfully implementing `shouldComponentUpdate` on each individual item brings a massive performance increase. I had failed to do this for a simple reason.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return !_.isEqual(nextProps, this.props);
}
```

However... I was doing this on my declaration of each item:

```
onClick={this.handleItemClick.bind(this, item.key)}
```

Which mean that `this.props.onClick === nextProps.onClick` would always return false, so every single item would always declare itself as needing to be rerendered. After implementing a custom check, it's extremely fast now!